# How was this sea effect done? Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How was this sea effect created? I tried googling for images but that was hopeless. I tried searching for things like "photoshop sea plugin" (and numerous other variations) but that was equally hopeless. I think it is a great effect and I would love to know how it was done.

[image: sea]

Comment: What part of this are you trying to figure out and what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

With the `Ocean Ripple` filter, located in Filter > Filter Gallery > Distort

I drew some random water, made up of varying shades of blue (more colors = more detail)

[image]

Tweak your filter settings

[image]

Not exact, but it's a good starting point.  This took me about 2-3 minutes, so with more effort, you can get better results.

[image]